# Old Peano theorem (demonstration is missing details)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $A, B :[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be two functions of class $C^{1}([a,b])$ such that two segments (or intervals) $[A(t_1),B(t_1)]$ and $[A(t_2), B(t_2)]$ never intersect for $t_1, t_2\in [a,b], \ t_1\neq t_2$. Prove that the area of the region described by the segment $[AB]$, $R=\{[A(t),B(t)] \ |\ t\in[a,b]\}$, can be computed by the formula:

$$\text{Area}(R)=\int_{a}^b \displaystyle\Big |\det\begin{pmatrix}x(t) & y(t) \\ x'(t) & y'(t) \end{pmatrix}\Big |\ \text{d}t$$

where $B(t)-A(t)=(x(t),y(t)), \ t\in[a,b]$.

P.S. For $U,V\in\mathbb{R}^2$, by the segment $[U,V]$ I mean the set $\{\lambda U+(1-\lambda)V,\ \lambda\in [0,1]\}$.

**Question:** Can there be found a similar formula in the space? (when $A, B :[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3)$

I found this propetry in a book of *Giuseppe Peano, Applicazioni geometriche del calcolo infinitesimale, 1887, page 238*, but I see that his proof is not complete, and I found some really hard problems in trying to fullfil it. You can find the book here: https://archive.org/details/applicazionigeo01peangoog

Note that this property is a nice generalization of *Mamikon Theorem* (see the book *New Horizons in Geometry,
by Tom M. Apostol* or simply search on the internet), found long time ago by *Peano*. This is why I'm asking for a generalization in $\mathbb{R}^3$, because *Mamikon theorem* works for space curves too. For details, see that article, pages 27-28: http://dolecki.perso.math.cnrs.fr/Peano=vulgarization_1307.pdf

Comment: It seems to me that the computation in the linked book ("Geometric applications of differential calculus") is clear and rigorous, as in Peano's style.  Of course, a reader of a textbook is supposed to start from the beginning, so I suppose you need to refer to the material in the previous part of this textbook in order that notations, definitions and properties used are clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$
I think that there is something wrong with the formula you wrote.  Suppose that

$$ A(t)=(t,0),\;\;B(t)=(t,1),\;\;\;t\in [0,1]. $$

In this case the segment $[A(t), B(t)]$ is the vertical segment from $(t,0)$ to $(t,1)$. The region $R$ is thus the unit square $[0,1]\times [0,1] \subset\bR^2$. We have $x=0$, $y=1$ so the integrand you wrote is $0$.

Here is one way to compute the area  of the region $R$ in the general case.  We introduce  new coordinates $(t,s)$ on $R$ as follows. Let

$$A(t)= ( p(t), q(t) )\;\;\; t\in [a,b]. $$

Every point $(u,v)$ in $R$ can be uniquely described by the parameters $t,s$

$$ u= p(t)+s x(t),\;\;v=q(t)+s y(t),   t\in [a,b], s\in [0,1]. $$

Geometrically  to locate a point in $R$ we first need to understand on which of the segments $[A(t), B(t)]$ it lies. This is the role of the parameter $t$. The parameter $s$    fixes the position of the point  on this segment.

We have

$$ du\wedge dv= \bigl(\dot p dt+s \dot{x} dt+xds\bigr)\wedge \bigl(\dot{q}dt+s\dot{y} dt +y ds\bigr) $$

$$=\bigl(\; (\dot{p}+s\dot{x})y-(\dot{q}+s\dot{y})x\;\bigr) dt\wedge ds $$

$$ =\underbrace{\bigl(\dot{p}y-\dot{q}x +s(\dot{x}y-\dot{y}x)\;\bigr)}_{\rho(t,s)} \;dt\wedge ds. $$

We deduce that

$$ {\rm Area}\;(R) =\pm\int_{[a,b]\times [0,1]}\rho(t,s) dt dt= \pm\int_a^b\bigl(\;(\dot{p}y-\dot{q}x ) +\frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}y-\dot{y}x)\;\bigr). $$

Note that in the special case described earlier we have $p=t$, $t=0$, $x=0$, $y=1$ $a=0$, $b=1$ and the above formula yields the correct answer.

Perhaps the generalization  you are looking for is the coarea formula. It states that for a  Riemann manifold $(M, g)$ and  $f: M\to\bR$ we have

$$ {\rm vol}\;(M,g) =\int_{\bR} \left(\int_{f^{-1}(t)} \frac{1}{|\nabla^g f(p)|} dV_{f^{-1}(t)}\right) dt. $$

Above $f^{-1}(t)$ is a smooth  hypersurface for  almost all $t$ and $dV_{f^{-1}(t)}$ is the volume element on this hypersurface  defined by the  induced metric.  In the case at  hand, use the function $f:R\to\bR$ described in the coordinates  by $f(t,s)=t$.

**Edit 1.** In $n$ dimensions $A(t)=(a^1,\dotsc, a^n(t))$, $X(t)=B(t)-A(t)=(x^1(t),\dotsc, x^n(t))$. Parametrize  the surface $R$ as above

$$ u^k=a^k(t)+sx^k(t),\;\;k=1,\dotsc, n,\;\;t\in [a,b],\;\; s\in [0,1]. $$

We have

$$du^k =(\dot{a}^k+s\dot{x}^k) dt +x^kds,\;\; k=1,\dotsc, n, $$

$$ (du^k)^2=  (\dot{a}^k+s\dot{x}^k)^2 dt^2 +2(\dot{a}^k+s\dot{x}^k)x^k dtds+(x^k)^2 ds^2,\;\;k=1,\dotsc, n. $$

The induced metric on $R$  is then

$$\sum_k (du^k)^2= \underbrace{\left(\sum_k(\dot{a}^k+s\dot{x}^k)^2 \right)}_{E}\,dt^2+ 2\;\underbrace{\left(\sum_k (\dot{a}^k+s\dot{x}^k)x^k\right)}_{F}\;dtds+\underbrace{\left(\sum_k (x^k)^2\right)}_{G}\; ds^2. $$

The area element on $R$ is then

$$dS=\sqrt{EG-F^2} dt ds. $$